# Initializing and Accessing 2D Arrays of strings in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, biopython, fasta

I'm trying to initialize a 2D matrix of sequences from a .fasta file in Python 3, but can not figure out how to properly initialize this where I can access the individual characters.

Ex.
I want to take:

```
s1 = "CATTAG"
s2 = "GGTCAC"
```

and do something like

```
matrix = [s1][s2]
```

which would form

`x C A T T A G
 G
 G
 T
 C
 A
 C`

Where I could individually access elements in the matrix and change their values like,

```
matrix[0][0] = 0
```

creating...

`x C A T T A G
 G 0
 G
 T
 C
 A
 C`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean to index matrix by the letters in "CATTAG" and "GGTCAC"?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Since there's two `'A'` in `'CATTAG'`, as well as two `'T'`, which column would you expect to index with `'A'` or `'T'`?

Comment: I would expect to access the first 'A' in CATTAG with matrix[0][1] since that's the 0th row and 1st column. @Grismar

Comment: So, you're not looking to index the matrix using the letters at all, you're just looking to index using two integers that happen to match what's in the strings?

Comment: Ah, you are looking to *store* the characters of the strings in the matrix as data, not as column headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're OK to use a library like `pandas`, this is an easy way to achieve your goal if the indices have unique values:

```
from itertools import product  # standard Python library
from pandas import Series, MultiIndex  # you may need to install this package `pandas`

s1 = 'CATG'
s2 = 'GTCA'
idx = MultiIndex.from_tuples(product(s1, s2)
df = Series(data=None, index=idx))

df['C']['G'] = 0

print(df)
```

However, since you provide indices that have duplicate values (i.e. two `'A'` and two `'T'` in `'CATTAG'`), you can't index those cells individually in a simple way.

The code would still work, but the results might be very confusing and probably not what you're looking for.

If you're just looking to index using integers, the solution is similar:

```
from itertools import product  # standard Python library
import pandas as pd  # you may need to install this package `pandas`

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(product(range(6), range(6)))
df = pd.Series(data=None, index=idx)

df[0][0] = 0

print(df)
```

A different approach (resulting an actual 2d matrix):

```
import pandas as pd  # you may need to install this package `pandas`

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(6), columns=pd.Series(range(6)))

df[0][0] = 0

print(df)
```

It appears you want to store the characters as data, which could be done - although it seems like a bad idea, you can use this alternate approach:

```
import pandas as pd  # you may need to install this package `pandas`

s1 = 'CATTAG'
s2 = 'GGTCAC'
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(s1)+1), columns=pd.Series(range(len(s2)+1)))

df.loc[0] = pd.Series(list('x'+s1))
df[0] = pd.Series(list('x'+s2))
df[1][1] = 0

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  x    C    A    T    T    A    G
1  G    0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  G  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  T  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  C  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

In case you're wondering about performance for larger DataFrames:

```
import timeit
import random
import pandas as pd  # you may need to install this package `pandas`


def define(size):
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(size), columns=pd.Series(range(size)))


def updates(x, size):
    global df
    for _ in range(x):
        df[random.randint(0, size-1)][random.randint(0, size-1)] = random.randint(0, 100)


print('create:', timeit.timeit(lambda: define(10000), number=2))
print('update:', timeit.timeit(lambda: updates(100000, 10000), number=2))
```

(runs each test twice, for 10,000 x 10,000 elements, 100,000 updates)

Result (in seconds):

```
create: 15.3850586
update: 20.7603317
```

Not lightning speed - but also not ages. You would get better performance using `numpy`, but you might lose some nice to use functionality. The original question didn't suggest data sizes this large. With `numpy`:

```
import timeit
import random
import numpy as np  # you may need to install this package `numpy`


def define(size):
    global arr
    arr = np.zeros(shape=(size, size))


def updates(x, size):
    global arr
    for _ in range(x):
        arr[random.randint(0, size-1)][random.randint(0, size-1)] = random.randint(0, 100)


print('create:', timeit.timeit(lambda: define(10000), number=2))
print('update:', timeit.timeit(lambda: updates(100000, 10000), number=2))
```

Faster by an order of magnitude:

```
create: 0.019482200000000005
update: 1.5629257
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Editing the values with >1000 indices seems to take an awfully long time. Is this an issue with Pandas?

Comment: @Julison if I define a pandas DataFrame with even 10,000x10,000 cells, the updates are not as slow as the initial setup. I'm adding some code to the answer - feel free to open a new question if you have questions about improving performance.